# Как добавить и удалить класс у одного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать проверку наличия класса у элемента, чтобы при клике на элемент, действие происходило многократно. Пробовал сделать, в конечном итоге действие происходит единожды, через toggleClass еще можно сделать, но там нужно будет дважды кликнуть, чтобы получить результат.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add-text").click(function(e) {
    if($("#add-text").hasClass("msg-error")) {
      $("#add-text").removeClass("msg-error");
    }

    if($("#text").val() == "") {
      $("#add-text").addClass("msg-error");

      return false;
    }
    
    return false;

  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { transform: translateX(-10px); }
  90% { transform: translateX(10px); }
}

.msg-error {
  animation: shake 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
        <input id="text" placeholder="введите текст"></input>
        <button id="add-text" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

  var $form = $('#form');

  $("#add-text", $form).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if( ! $("#text", $form).val() ) {
      $(this).addClass("msg-error");

      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#add-text", $form).removeClass("msg-error");
      }, 600);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
@keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { transform: translateX(-10px); }
  90% { transform: translateX(10px); }
}

.msg-error {
  animation: shake 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
        <input id="text" placeholder="введите текст"></input>
        <button id="add-text" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: а для чего form добавил?

Comment: Чтобы можно было сразу проверить работоспособность. Так нельзя делать?